# Lookup On Table Using Wildcards:

Tags: informatica

I have this requirement, where my lookup table is:

```
Fi  Sortorder
003 Transit
002 Serial
001 Transit,Serial
0** Transit,Account
*** Account
```

I want to look up on this table on FI field from source, so here problem is how will I search for the wild cards, in Source I will always get 3 digits in FI col, so lookin up on exact 3 digit is fine but how to lookup for last 2 digits and extract its sortorder col.

If I use wildcards then there might be possibility that wrong sortorder will be taken so I have to lookup with more precise information. Also there are 100s of combination and entries its just an example. I don't need full solution with syntax and all, I am just looking for approach. I will post my solution soon which I am trying right now if you guys think of anything kindly let me know.

Comment: Hi, can you give some background to why you don't want to use a lookup transformation. I'm also stumped why the sort order of a lookup makes any difference. Usual lookup strategy with Infomatica is to match ports from the pipeline against your lookup key as the lookup condition i.e. no coded expression for the match so I'm struggling to see where wildcards affect this

Comment: The Lookup doesn't allow anything apart comparison operators. You could go through multiple steps : first lookup that match on 3 numbers. If that doesn't match, then replace the last character of the source data with a wildcard and go through a second lookup. Repeat this steps by replacing more characters with wildcards. If it's up to only 3 numbers, you need 4 Lookup, I hope there aren't too many lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do a lookup using less number of characters, just use a substring. And create a lookup for each number of characters you need. Eg. if you need to match using last 2 digits (TSQL):

- use `select right(Fi, 2) from yourtable` as lookup SQL override
- do a substring on your port in expression transformation to get last 2 characters from Fi port
- use if for lookup condition

Just make sure to set the order and `Lookup policy on multiple match` according to your needs.